# Can convolution be equivalent to Controlled differential equation?

Tags: soft-question, convolution, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider this equation (convolution of two functions)

$dy(t)=f(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau$.

For the case when $g$ and $f$ are continuous and continuously differentiable functions, we can say that it is well-defined. However if one function say $f$ is a random variable/random noise (continuous but nondifferentiable) then can we write the above equation in the form of a controlled differential equation in higher dimension $d$:

$dY_t^i=\sum_{j = 1}^{d}V_j^i(Y_t)dX_t^j$.

In other words, are we solving some Controlled differential equation when one of the functions of a convolution is a random variable? The unknown noise can we model as a contribution from additional dimensions.

**Edit:** I realized that the question is not clear and it can be very specific. In many applications $y(t)$ is known and we need to estimate $f$. But generally, $f$ is added with Gaussian Noise so, I am wondering if we can formulate the equation like stochastic differential so that we can have a solution option.

**EDIT** Changed from Stochastic to Controlled as it is more appropriate.

**EDIT** It may be equivalent to say can we formulate each independent time sample as an additional space dimension?

Comment: The convolution equation is well-defined for just integrable $g$ and $f$. If $f(\tau,\omega)$ is also a random variable for every $\tau$ then $y(t,\omega)$ will be a RV for every $t\,.$ We do not have to introduce a SDE with a Brownian motion.

Comment: @KurtG. the question is not " we do not have to" question is can we?

Comment: @KurtG. can you explain thingh without omega please?

Comment: (I don't know why my web browser deleted the '@Creator' I started this comment with). You may want to give a bit of background, in particular why the $\omega$ is prohibited when -as you say- $f$ is a random variable.

Comment: @KurtG. It is not about prohibited, I had a function with one variable and want to keep it that way.  Instead of introduction of new varaible can we change the differential; is exactly is the question. Thank you for your interest in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The equation for $y$ is equivalent to
$$
y(t)=y(0)+\int_0^t f(\tau)\,g(t-\tau)\,d\tau\,.
$$
Differentiating with respect to $t$ yields
$$
y'(t)=f(t)\,g(0)+\int_0^tf(\tau)\,g'(t-\tau)\,d\tau\,.
$$
If you want to bring this into an SDE/ODE form $dy(t)=\mu(y(t),t)\,dt+\sigma(y(t),t)\,dB_t$ it is clear than you can choose $\sigma\equiv 0$ (which makes it an ODE). When
$$
g(s)=e^{as}\,,\quad g'(s)=a\,g(s)
$$
then clearly
$$
y'(t)=f(t)+a\int_0^tf(\tau)\,g(t-\tau)\,d\tau=f(t)+a\,(y(t)-y(0))\,.
$$
Therefore, for this particular $g$ you take $\mu(y,t)=f(t)+ay-ay(0)\,.$

Are these enough hints ? Perhaps a general $g$ can be handled using the Laplace transform.

Comment: We are talking about f as random variable and the question is can we bring the randomness into dB and you making it to 0. I am sorry you are not asnwering the question. I will have to downvote at this form.

Comment: @Creator, feel free to downvote whatever you want. It is quite obvious that my derivations allows for $f$ being a random variable. I did not make this expiclit because you were prohibiting the use of $\omega\,.$

Comment: Downvote is not for your answer incorrect but is for not answering the question asked. The possible answer can be " No one cannot write the equation in terms of differential dB because..." or write it in terms of differential dB. In the present form f(t) itself is in the y'(t). It is nowhere answering the question.